Gen 32:1-2; why did God send Angels to meet Jacob after he met Laban?
Gen 32:1-2; significance for God sending Angels to meet Jacob after his meeting/confrontation with Laban.

Jacob also went on his way, and the angels of God met him. When
Jacob saw them, he said, “This is the camp of God.” So he named that
place Mahanaim.


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Note the comments of Ellicott on Gen 7:1-

Angels of God.—Numberless conjectures have been hazarded as to who were these “messengers of Elohim,” and how they were seen by Jacob.
... More probably, as Jacob on his road to Padan-Aram had been assured
of God’s watchful care of him by the vision of the angels ascending
and descending the stairs, so now also in a dream he sees the angels
encamped on each side of him, to assure him of protection against his
brother.

The Pulpit commentary is also helpful:

Verse 1. - And Jacob (after Laban's departure) went on his way (from
Galeed and Mizpah, in a southerly direction towards the Jabbok), and
the angels of God - literally, the messengers of Elohim, not chance
travelers who informed him of Esau's being in the vicinity
(Abarbanel), but angels (cf. Psalm 104:4) - met him. Not necessarily
came in an opposite direction, fuerunt ei obviam (Vulgate), but simply
fell in with him, lighted on him as in Genesis 28:11, συνήντησαν αὐτῶ
(LXX.), forgathered with him (Scottish); but whether this was in a
waking vision (Kurtz, Keil, Inglis) or a midnight dream (Hengstenberg)
is uncertain, though-the two former visions enjoyed by Jacob were at
night (cf. Genesis 28:12; Genesis 31:10). Cajetan, approved by
Pererius, translating בּו "in him," makes it appear that the vision
was purely subjective, non fuisse visionem corporalem, sed internam:
the clause interpolated by the LXX., καὶ ἀναβλέψας εἰδε παρεμβολὴν
θεοῦ παρμεβεβληκυῖαν, seems rather to point to an objective
manifestation. The appearance of this invisible host may have been
designed to celebrate Jacob's triumph over Laban, as after Christ's
victory over Satan in the wilderness angels came and ministered unto
him (Rupertus, Wordsworth), or to remind him that he owed his
deliverance to Divine interposition (Calvin, Bush, Lange), but was
more probably intended to assure him of protection in his approaching
interview with Esau (Josephus, Chrysostom, Rosenmüller, Keil, Murphy,
'Speaker's Commentary'), and perhaps also to give him welcome in
returning home again to Canaan (Kurtz), if not in addition to suggest
that his descendants would require to fight for their inheritance
(Kalisch). Genesis 32:1


Why is it considered a possible dream, in stead of an actual encounter

"So now also in a dream he sees the angels encamped  on either side of him". In the Pulpet commentary it alludes to a waking vision or a midnight dream. Clarification please

@Edward - while Jacob may or may not have seen them in a dream, the angels were still real and an anticipation of the promise in Ex 23:20-23.
